# How do I start redis as a rakefile task

Tags: ruby, rake, redis, rakefile

I am trying to create a rakefile that runs both redis and irb. I have figured out how to run IRB (the first task runs), but when I try to run the redis task I see the error:

rake aborted! wrong number of arguments

Exactly what is wrong? My code is below:

```
task :default do
  require 'irb' 
  IRB.start
end

task :init do
  require 'redis'
  exec {'redis-server'}
end
```

Command I use to run the code:

bundle exec rake (or rake :init, depending on which one I want to run)

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving an argument error because `exec` expects a string argument, and you are sending it a block. `exec` does not do anything with your block and wants a string.

Use `exec "redis-server"` to execute the command correctly.

Hopefully the result is what you are looking for. Not sure why you are requiring redis at all since you aren't using the gem, you are just executing a command. The behavior of this task would be no different than just running `redis-server` on the command line.